# Python running version 2.7 despite in a conda 3.8 environment

Tags: macos, conda, python-3.8, macos-big-sur

I created and activated a conda environment with python 3.8. When calling `python` it systematically runs Python version 2.7 instead of 3.8.

```sh
(base) $ conda create -n py38 python=3.8

(base) $ conda activate py38

(py38) $ python --version
Python 2.7.16

(py38) $ which python
/usr/bin/python

(py38) $ which python3.8
/Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/python3.8
```

In `$PATH` there is effectively `/usr/bin` but I'm surprised that conda doesn't override that while the environment is running. Also, there is no `python` alias to be found in any of the possible configuration files (.bashrc, .zshrc, .bash_profile, .profile or any other).

How can I get the `python` command to correctly run Python 3.8 while the `py38` env is active?

Generally speaking, how to get conda to run the correct Python version "once and for all" in any new environment I would create in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure when you are in `(py38)` by :

```
echo $PATH
```

that `/Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin` is before `/usr/bin`

then run

```
cd /Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin
ln -fs python3.8 python3
ln -fs python3   python
```

Comment: While I agree they need to verify that PATH is getting manipulated correctly by Conda, but there should not be a need for manually creating softlinks - Conda should already be doing that upon installation of Python in the environment.